# Как правильно установить python-levenshtein

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, установка, levenshtein

При попытке установить библиотеку `python-levenshtein` (через `pip install python-levenshtein`) выдает ошибку:

```
Complete output (27 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein\StringMatcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Levenshtein
    running egg_info
    writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt
    writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying Levenshtein\_levenshtein.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein\_levenshtein.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Levenshtein
    running build_ext
    building 'Levenshtein._levenshtein' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Как это можно исправить? Есть ли другие аналоги `levenshtein`?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть хорошая библиотека [jellyfish](https://pypi.org/project/jellyfish/). Для расчета расстояниея Ливенштейна (редакционное расстояние, т.е. сколько изменений нужно сделать, чтобы превратить одно слово в другое), достаточно вызвать метод levenshtein_distance:

```
import jellyfish
>>> jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(u'jellyfish', u'smellyfish')
2
```

А ошибка установки python-levenshtein говорит о необходимости в Microsoft Visual C++ от версии 14.0 и выше.

Comment: О не знал... ;)