# Установка python-Levenshtein

Tags: python, visual-c++, build-error

Я установил python-Levenshtein с помощью команды pip3 install python_Levenshtein но эта команда выбила мне ошибку '''error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/'''](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/%27%27%27) Вообщем загуглил, понял, установил программу Visual Studio Build Tools 2019. Выбрал средства сборки C++, вроде скачалось и установилось, но когда опять набрал pip3 install python_Levenshtei то оно выбивает ту же ошибку. Также попытался установить Python-Levenshtain с сайта [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein) но оно мне тоже выдало ошибку:  ERROR: python_Levenshtein-0.12.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Облазил весь интернет, но ответа на мой вопрос не нашёл, помогите найти способ установить python-Levenshtein

Wheel - установлен

Python - версия 3.9

платформа - Windows 10 x64

Comment: Проверьте, платформы на которых можно скачать `python-Levenshtein` и подходит ли ваша платформа для скачки этого дополнения.

Comment: а собственно сам `wheel` установлен?

Comment: Операционная система 64 бит или 32 бита? Какая версия Питона?

Comment: @Kers Да, установлен

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Операционная - 64 бит, Python - 3.9

Comment: Вы пытались поставить 32-битную версию. Вам нужна `python_Levenshtein‑0.12.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо всё работает!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Был рад помочь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229048/420098